# Match the last " in a string in vim

Tags: regex, vim

When searching in VIM I would like to find the following:

```
''
```

What I am doing is:

```
/''
```

That will however put my cursor to the first '

How can I search for that but only match the last occurence of the

```
'
```

I was trying something like this:

```
/'$(?<=')/g
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yep that works. However the cursor is at the first ' then. I'd have to manually go right. The solution Kent mentions solves that problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want to put your cursor at the end of your searching patter, you could add an offset in your `/patter/offset`

e.g. try:

```
/''/e<Enter>
```

if you want to place your cursor at the char next to the matched end, you do:

```
/''/e+1<Enter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead with vim's (in my opinion) unusual syntax

```
'\(.*'\)\@!
```

This will match a `'` that does not have another `'` that follows it anywhere on the line

Answer (score 1):

Another option: `\zs` changes where the start of a match is. So you could do `/'\zs'` to do what you want. (`\ze`, by the way, is its counterpart for setting the end of a match.